# How do I use a photodiode for arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, sensors, servo

I am doing a project that requires me to program an arduino to sense changes of a steady stream of light due to the scattering of that light. If the phootodiode does change its resistance to the current, then a flap will turn a certain number of degrees. I'm not sure how to operate a photodiode, but know the basics of how it works.

The apparatus is designed to increase the operating life of a solar panel on Mars. When dust from a dust storm collects on its surface, a photodiode will detect the change in light and change its resistance to a current running through it. Then a flap connected to the solar panel will close to cover the solar panel. I'm using Hitec HS-311 Standard servo to rotate  the flap, but I've had some problems operating it.

Comment: A photodiode does not change resistance. It generates a tiny current when light strikes it.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/73732/how-to-use-sfh235-ir-photodiode-correctly

Comment: photodioides are rare and relativily expensive; you probably want a light-dependent resistor (cds), which makes for easy analog-input voltage-divider circuits. Or a phototransistor, which works like a regular transistor and can control a digital input easily.

Answer (score -1):

try to use an opamp to create a voltage output from the diode. you can then adc that voltage output from the mcu.

Comment: Could you be more specific please?